# Requirements OS X Brew libs install error

Tags: ruby, rvm, homebrew

I am trying to make a clean install from RVM to my MacBook and I have a lot of work with the RVM requirements. I started to install separately, but I have this error:

```
$ rvm requirements
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date.
Installing required packages: libxml2, libxslt........
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install libxml2 libxslt',
please read /Users/myuser/.rvm/log/1370499182_package_install_libxml2_libxslt.log
```

The log has these messages:

```
[2013-06-05 23:00:55] requirements_osx_brew_libs_install
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2
Warning: For non-brewed Python, you have to set the PYTHONPATH in order to
find brewed Python modules.
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
Error: File exists - /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
```

I'm installing RVM to work on Ruby on Rails projects.

I hope you can guide me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

install this two packages:

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt
```

after they are available from homebrew rvm will just use them and continue with ruby installation

Comment: I received the next error message:      Warning: For non-brewed Python, you have to set the PYTHONPATH in order to
find brewed Python modules.
  export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
Error: File exists - /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: is it only this? it looks more like a warning, check if the packages are installed `brew list -1 | \grep libxml2`? make sure to show whole output/log.

Comment: So I used brew to install all the dependencies except libxml2 and that was enough to satisfy RVM. Not sure what the issue was, but this seemed to work around it